# Cannot install fastecdsa in Linux error: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I have spent 6 hours trying to get fastcdsa to install successfully with no luck. I'm not a linux person but it'ts better for programming so I'm trying to switch from Windows. I have tried several version support by Python 3.7 which is the version I'm using, I have tried every fix I could find with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

**$sudo pip3 install --use-pep517 fastecdsa==2.2.2**

Collecting fastecdsa==2.2.2
Using cached fastecdsa-2.2.2.tar.gz (48 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: -11
╰─> [11 lines of output]
running dist_info
creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info
writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-83zjk2ye/fastecdsa-2.2.2.dist-info'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 0):

Also, verify that have installed the following dependencies: [fastecdsa installation](https://pypi.org/project/fastecdsa/#installing).